# Spring - specifying key-value pairs in spring config file

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have a `DefaultProcessor.java` that processes files for different products (some 50 products). So the product specific beans are configured in spring config files (one spring-config file per product).

Now I have some 2-3 product-specific properties (key-value pairs) also. So I was wondering to have those properties in the config file itself instead of having one properties file per product.

**Q1.** Is it possible to specify key-value pairs in spring-config file without creating a bean?

**Q2.** If it is not possible, then Is it a good practice to create an `Environment.java` class having `Map<String, String>` as a property and then configure that bean in each product-specific config file instead of having those properties in a **.properties** file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [util:map](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-map)

From the spring docs:

```
<util:map id="emails">
    <entry key="pechorin" value="pechorin@hero.org"/>
    <entry key="raskolnikov" value="raskolnikov@slums.org"/>
    <entry key="stavrogin" value="stavrogin@gov.org"/>
    <entry key="porfiry" value="porfiry@gov.org"/>
</util:map>
```

You can then inject the map using normal spring setter/constructor mechanisms

Comment: @YatendraGoel: I'm not sure what you ask, but you can do this: `<bean ...><property...><util:map><entry.../> <entry.../></util:map></property></bean>`

Comment: @Max I know I can do this. I wanted to know Is it possible to access this map without declaring a bean?

Comment: you mean to have a reference to a map from outside the spring container?